# Energy of classical Inverted Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, hamiltonian-formalism, oscillators

Quick one.
Does the energy of inverted harmonic oscillator

$$H(x, p) = \frac{p^2}{2} - \frac{x^2}{2},$$

remain conserved?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: @Qmechanic Oh that should definitely be an answer! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because $\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=0$. Or working with the Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2$, we can use $\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0$.